# Access information from a list

Tags: c#

The list contains a text file with Nutrient information in it e.g
 (honey  0  30  100  40  20 40) each number being a nutirient in grams
 e.g (Sugar, sodium, fat etc..).

```
public string GetNutrients (List<string> n)
{
 // n is the nutrient list
 string ingredient = txtEnterIngredients.Text;
```

I need to look for ingredient in the List and take the whole line of data which would be (`Ingredient 0 0 0 0 0 0`), Then only take the Numbers and return them to another method.

Comment: What is `txtEnterIngredients`? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: And you should learn classes or at least JSON rather than storing unstructured data in strings.

Comment: `return n.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Split(' ')[0] == ingredient);` should return the full line for the ingredient. You can then split it by ' ' and get the numbers.

Comment: TxtEnterIngredients is a text box where the user puts in an ingredient.

Comment: if it's a text file, then why not read the text file directly rather than requiring the user to enter the information into a text box. If it has to be entered by the user, why not use multiple text boxes for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're asking how to [split a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split) and [array access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#indexer-operator-)

```
// declare totals
var totalSugar = 0;

foreach (var x in n) {
    string[] parts = x.split(' ');

    // parse it
    var i = x[0];
    if ( i == "some ingredient" ) // filter it 
    {
        var sugar = x[1];  // accumulate it
        totalSugar += sugar;
    }
}
// do something with data
Console.WriteLine(totalSugar);
```

Note: Probably easier to [use LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)